# Error creating bean with name 'Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'Repository'

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

i've been trying do some application with spring-boot and hibernate the last few days, i could correct all the errors, but this one i can't understand...

i have created 3 packages : Model which contains my 4 models (user,account,note and notebook)
Repository
and Web which contains my controllers

Here is my Controller :

```
@Component
@RestController
public class NotebookRestController{
    @Autowired
    private NotebookRepository notebookRepository;

    @GetMapping(value="/getAllNoteBooks")
    public List<Notebook> getAllNotebooks(@RequestParam(name="uId") Long uid){
       List<Notebook> NotebookList = notebookRepository.findAllByUser_UId(uid);
       return NotebookList;
    }
}
```

my Repository code :

```
@Repository
public interface NotebookRepository extends JpaRepository<Notebook, Long> {

    @Query("select e from Notebook e where Notebook.user.uId=:x")
    List<Notebook> findAllByUser_UId(@Param("x") long x);
}
```

and the error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'notebookRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'notebookRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notebookRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.notedemo.repository.NotebookRepository.findAllByUser_UId(long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.notedemo.NotedemoApplication.main(NotedemoApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notebookRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.notedemo.repository.NotebookRepository.findAllByUser_UId(long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.notedemo.repository.NotebookRepository.findAllByUser_UId(long)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:566) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:561) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:385) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:366) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:659) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5002) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExprLhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5614) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4987) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1286) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4706) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4174) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2138) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:815) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:609) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your scroll the first line of error stacktrace to the right, then you'll see that it says:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.notedemo.repository.NotebookRepository.findAllByUser_UId(long)```

So your custom JPQL query in your repo is invalid.

If your `Notebook` class has a member of type `User` called `user` and accessors (getter/setter) and this `User` class has a member of type `java.lang.Long` called `uId` (also with accessors)... then try changing your query to:

`select e from Notebook e where e.user.uId=:x`

After that, if it still doesn't work, try using the full qualified classname of your `Notebook` class in your query.

FYI: Maybe you should try out Spring Data JPA... makes things simple quite often:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the stack trace, and read it carefully, you can figure this out.

The first exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: **Error creating bean with name 'notebookRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'notebookRepository';** nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'notebookRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.notedemo.repository.NotebookRepository.findAllByUser_UId(long)!

OK, so it failed creating `notebookRestController` because there was a problem creating `notebookRepsitory`.  Let's continue:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.notedemo.repository.NotebookRepository.findAllByUser_UId(long)!**

Ah, so the problem is with the query! It failed parsing the query, so it failed to create `NotebookRepository`, and since it required that repository to create `NotebookRestController`, it failed to create that as well. Makes perfect sense.

So, the problem is with the query

```sql
select e from Notebook e where Notebook.user.uId=:x
```

I think the problem is you are using `Notebook` instead of `e`. I would try

```sql
select e from Notebook e where e.user.uId=:x
```

Comment: You're welcome! Just so you know, the preferred way of saying "thanks" around here is upvoting any helpful answers, and accepting the one (if any) that provided the best solution to your problem.

Comment: i'm sorry, i was in work the moment i demanded that and i havent logged in since the, i'm sorry and thank you for your time!